# Hand-entered data into a text-box isn't recognized by $("#id_name").text(); in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery autocomplete and I slightly adjusted the autocomplete to also enable people to add things that are not in the database by entering data right into the a textbox.  Here is an example of this:

http://www.problemio.com/test.php

The problem I am having is that when a person writes directly into the textbox and presses the add button, the system does not pick up what was written in the textbox.  The code I have to get the value of that field is:

```
var categories = $("#log").text();
```

Any ideas for how to get the value of the textarea when the add button is pressed if you write in the textarea by hand?

Thanks!!

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. You say that the problem is when the user writes into the textbox directly, but then say you want the value of the textarea instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textarea is part of a form. 
It doesn't have a text() value, instead it has a val().

`var categories = $("#log").val();`

Comment: that didn't quite work.  Possibly it has something to do with the log() function which does this: $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );

Comment: Worked with some more tweeking.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use val instead of text

```
var categories = $("#log").val();
```